# JDK and Eclipse not working properly

Tags: eclipse, environment-variables, adt, java

Okay, so i wiped my PC clean today. Upon attempting to install Eclipse and the JDK i hit a snag.

- I install the "ADT Bundle" from android developers.
- I install the JDK to the default path

When i try to open Eclipse, it cannot find my JRE (which from what i understand comes in the JDK which i downloaded from the oracle website). I know it is properly installed because i can navigate to the install path and run java programs using the exe.

iv heard something about modifying environment variables to get it to find it but nothing has worked... i dont have a "PATH" variable listed.... i do have a "Path"... but changing either one does nothing to fix the problem... I have done this installation many times and it SHOULD be working...

any help on the subject would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can specify path in `eclipse.ini`. Just add as first line this `-vm c:\your\path\to\java\home\bin\javaw`

Comment: please paste the error message which you get while opening of eclipse

Comment: @freak i have screenies at this link>> http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/40262/help-jdk-and-eclipse-not-working-properly#comment54660_40262

Answer (score 0):

Since you wiped it clean, have you tried downloading Java Runtime Environment again (maybe you wiped it too)

Comment: This is pretty blunt, but try running the exe as admin

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this problem is such:

The "Path" enviroment variable needs to be under -user variables- NOT system variables
make a new user variable named "Path" and set the value to the absolute path of the java compiler

for me it was something like C:\Program File\Java\JDK1.7\bin

that should fix the problem of eclipse not finding the JDK/JRE...

if it complains about "JNI" then you need to make sure you are running the JDK and eclipse as the same achitechture (64bit java wont work with 32bit eclipse)

Answer (score 0):

The "Path" environment variable needs to be defined or updated. If you are working in Windows 8 then you can navigate by following these steps:

1. Open > File Explorer
2. Right Click "Computer"
3. Select "Properties"
4. On the left hand side select "advanced system settings"
5. Under the "Advanced" tab, select "Environment Variables"
6. Locate the Path directory in the list under System
7. Edit the directory by entering a semi-colon after the last entry and then manually typing the location of your Java directory.
8. After the full address is entered, (Should look similar to --> C:\Program File\Java\JDK1.7\bin) click "Ok" on the screen to save your changes.

Something to keep in mind while updating your path. Make sure that you direct the path to the compatible version. If you downloaded the 64 bit eclipse, choose the 64 bit Java. If you do not remember the Eclipse version you downloaded, check your download file name against the files offered on Eclipse's website. If you follow these steps Eclipse should open up without a problem.